# Test keyboard presence after touching on a textbox

Tags: android, keyboard

I am writing a test cases based off Instrumentation Framework to test an activity of an app esp.

1. Touch on a textbox
2. Verify whether keyboard comes up?

I am able to simulate touching on textbox using instrumentation..it works. But, I am stuck with 2nd step.

Could someone help me with this?